# What is .indices meaning in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to know actually how .indices works and what is the main difference is between this two for loops.

```
for (arg in args)
    println(arg)
```

or

```
for (i in args.indices)
    println(args[i])
```

And what is use of `withIndex()` function

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

Comment: please refer to the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are just different ways to iterate over an array, depending on what you need access to within the body of the `for` loop: the current element (first case), the current index (second case), or both (third case).

If you're wondering about how they work under the hood, you can just jump into the code of the Kotlin runtime (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in IntelliJ), and find out.

For [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) specifically, this is pretty simple, it's implemented as an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) that returns an `IntRange` which a `for` loop can then iterate over:

```
/**
 * Returns the range of valid indices for the array.
 */
public val <T> Array<out T>.indices: IntRange
    get() = IntRange(0, lastIndex)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that iterating over an array indices is optimized and compiled to an equivalent of a regular while-loop over indices, without an `IntRange` creation.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for where that is documented see [For Loops - Control Flow - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops): "Note that this 'iteration through a range' is compiled down to optimal implementation with no extra objects created."

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation **indices** is the index value from the list.

> Returns an IntRange of the valid indices for this collection.

For more details refer to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html)

Answer (score 1):

`indices` returns `IntRange`(range of index from first to the last position) of collection, for example:

```
val array= arrayOf(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)

println("Indices: "+array.indices) // output: Indices: 0..6
```

In the question, both the loop are doing the same thing and just different way of iterate any collection(as @zsmb13 mentioned) but, the 2nd for loop does not create an iterator object as the first one does.

`indices` returns `IntRange` so you must check [these](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) useful methods of `IntRange`

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote

```
for (i in 0..searchResultsTemp.items.size-1 )
        { " la-la-la "},
```

I wanted to work with each item of the collection, but I wouldn't use forEach operator, I would have access to the index of the collection item.
Then the built-in Android Studio helper suggested to me to automatically replace this expression with

```
 for (i in searchResultsTemp.items.indices)
        { " la-la-la "}
```

It is the same.